# datatables not returning other query for add columns

Tags: laravel, datatables

***This does not return any result for user table***

```
 $user=user::all();
 $audits=audits::all(); 

 return Datatables::of(audits::query())
    ->setRowId('id')
    ->addColumn('usertype', function($user) {

        return  $user->name;


    })
```

***Joining table also not return user table data only return audits table data***

```
     $jointable= DB::table('audits')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', 'audits.user_id')
    ->select('users.user_type')
    ->orderBy('audits.id')
    ->get();

     return Datatables::of(audits::query())
    ->setRowId('id')
    ->addColumn('usertype', function($jointable) {

      //not let me return user table data gives me nothing

        return  $jointable;

      //this return audits data

       return  $jointable->events;


    })
```

is it because? return Datatables::of(audits::query()) only accepts audits table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use this with the join query you mentioned

```
return Datatables::of($jointable)->make(true);
```